# Acer Iconia A500 not in adb devices

Tags: android, adb

Just picked up an Iconia A500 (yay $100 off coupon) and started messing with it playing games, etc.

I decided it was finally time to work, fired up adb and launched eclipse to test an app and I discovered it wasn't in my devices list. I've tried installing the acer drivers. It puts a folder in my Program Files directory...but I don't see what I'm supposed to do there. There's "EUUDriverInstaller" but when I click on it nothing (seems to) happens.

When I plug the device in it uses some generic Microsoft driver to show the device contents but composite adb doesn't show up at all like it does for my Droid.

I've reboot several times on both device and laptop.
I've uninstalled / reinstalled the application that made that driver directory.
I opened an application in the driver directory under the x64 folder and it opened up the windows driver installer and installed some drivers...but still no composite adb when I plug it in.
It is on usb debugging and I've toggled it on and off.

It's running 3.1 stock
I'm on x64 Windows 7

Both command prompt adb devices is empty under "List of devices attached" and Eclipse devices is empty.
My sdk is fully updated.

Comment: It seems like my situation is comparable to this guy in regards to the device just being treated like a flash drive.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=734139
He says the rom was the problem...but I can't see why this stock rom should have an issue.

Comment: Where did you get that acer drivers please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved the same problem by this way: connect your device, start Device Manager, find missing device driver, select update driver and browse the folder with acer drivers.

Comment: The only item I can update is "Acer Iconia Tab A500" under Portable Devices. Currently it's using a Microsoft Driver for a "MTP USB Device". It won't "update" to anything else. And plugging it in isn't triggering the composite adb for me to update either. The folder it added to my program files only contains "EUUDriverInstaller" and a folder called Win7 with a folder called adb within it. It is full of adb relevant files, but like I said there's no adb in device manager.

Comment: You can try to remove drivers using Device Manager and reconnect device or connect your device to another usb port. Acer's driver setup utility doesn't really install driver but only copies file. You need to force Windows 7 to lookup drivers for new device.

Comment: WOW, switching USB ports did it...I feel like such a tool. THANK YOU!

Comment: lol I had the same thing.. messing with drivers all night, just needed to change USB ports!

Comment: cheers mate, worked switching usb port for me as well... with debug mode active.

Comment: On Windows 8.1 x64 I used the "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer" option and updated the driver to Google Galaxy Nexus ADB Interface as there was nothing in the list that mentioned any Acer device. This worked fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

Yet another set of symptoms, and another answer....

A500 using 3.2 roms (I have other 4.x devices, so I'm saving this one). Using Windows 8. Downloaded and installed the Acer 1.06 drivers. Have previously isntalled Google ADB drivers for the Nexus 7 from android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\amd64 (or i386 if that's appropriate), but that may not be required.

Plug in the A500, and launch device manager. The Acer Iconia Tab A500 device shows up in "Other Devices" folder but with no drivers installed. Click on the device, click on "Update Driver". Select "Browse my Computer". Click "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer". From that list, select "Android Device". Select "Google" as manufacturer, and select "Android ADB Interface" as the Model. CLick "next". Click "Yes really, really do it please". Done.

Edit:

On windows 8.1, the behavior is different again. The device will show up in the "Android Device" folder. Right click on that, and proceed as described above to select and isntall the "Android ADB Interface" driver. I'm having to do this with all my devices. Windows 8.1 seems to istall everything BUT the ADB driver, which you need to forcibly install using this procedure.

Comment: Partially.
Very strange thing.
I swapped the USB port , followed your suggestions to try installing the Google driver (as I know that Acer is the actual manufacturer of the Nexus 7)... but found only one Acer ADB composite drever, used that one and it works :P

Can't figure otu why. I did this same thing a few times yesterday on a laptop with no results.

Well, it's working at least. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Acer A500 drivers are available here:

http://www.acer.com.au/ac/en/AU/content/drivers

(Select Tablets > Iconia > A500)

Direct link:

http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/USB/USB_Acer_1.06.1500_A30H_A.zip?acerid=634387730136042972&Step1=Tablet&Step2=ICONIA%20Tab&Step3=A500&OS=a05&LC=en&BC=Acer&SC=PA_6

Answer (score 3):

Acer Iconia A100 won't allow USB debugging on Win7 - Android 3.2.1 - No doubt a similar problem to the A500 described above.

USB debugging enabled, connected to Win7 x64 - "adb devices" would not find the tablet, nor would DDMS, which I need for screenshots (don't want to root the tablet).

Folks here are right: Win 7 is single-minded about using its own driver for this tablet, and the Acer installer simply drops the files onto the drive. In fact, it drops them onto the drive, then seeing that the Windows driver is already in place, happily deletes the Win7 drivers it has copied out of the installer. I spent an hour in Device Manager trying to con Win7 into using the Acer drivers, but it kept telling me they were not compatible.

MY SOLUTION:
1. Run Device Manager with tablet attached.
2. Update driver software.
3. Browse my computer for driver software
4. Let me pick from a list...
5. Select USB Composite Device.

Win7 insists that the A100 is a MTP USB device, whatever that means.

Finally, I told Win7 to pound sand and selected "USB Composite Device". Immediately "adb devices" found it.

Ahhhh. I can DDMS again.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem on Windows 8.  The installer did not work for me, and since the actual drivers installer comes packed in an EXE so you can't install manually. Here's how to fix:

1. Run the EXE provided by Acer.
2. Now locate the `ACER ICONA 3G DRIVER INSTALL .msi` file.  I couldn't find where the installer was copying the msi manually, so I used the sysinternals utility `handle.exe` to tell me which files the installer had open.

`handle -p "ICONIA TAB USB DRIVER SETUP.exe"`

1. Once you've located the installer, copy it to a temp folder and extract the contents. I used 7-zip for the task.
2. Use the device manager to manually locate and install the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, plug again and again (and again?) didn't help me.. neither did switching usb ports..
It really took me 3 days search quite a lot of post threads to solve the problem.
Just come back to share with those stopped by the same puzzle :)

Reference: [Connect to Android with ADB over TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

The above instruction requires a PC which can ADB to your tablet over usb.
Better work-around is root your device firstly, and then download a adbWireless,
so you can switch your tablet to ADB TCP mode even without USB connection at all.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Just change USB ports, worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but you may have to root the Iconia to get ADB. I will be trying this later tonight and I will check back.

http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-root-acer-iconia-a500-honeycomb-tablet/

EDIt
Figured it out, you need the ACER USB driver from their website (http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=3851). Installing that got it working for me.

Comment: I was starting to think that, but the first step of rooting is:

adb push c:\Gingerbreak-v1.20.apk /data/local

So I can't see how you'd get around needing adb working first.

Comment: Did you just install only what was unzipped? I've installed that and nothing changes for me.

Comment: I ran the setup.exe from the zip, plugged and unplugged the device twice and it eventually showed up in adb devices. Perhaps trying Danil's suggestion might help.

Comment: When you have it plugged in does it still show the tablet under portable devices and using the microsoft driver as a separate entry than the adb entry?

Comment: Yes, it shows up as a portable device, and under Device Manager as ADB Interface -> ACER composite ADB interface

Comment: It seems like the tablet is going straight to mounting if that means anything. Connecting my droid doesn't bring up the Autoplay menu while connecting the tablet automatically asks me how I want to access the data.

Comment: Yeah...I don't have that ADB Interface popping up for it.

Comment: It doesn't even ask to mount it...it goes straight for it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, but it pointed me in the right direction.  I had to hack the drivers similar to http://www.davinciunltd.com/2011/10/hacking-the-adb-usb-driver-for-acer-a500/ and then manually point the drivers to the hacked inf.

My device hardware ID and the inf file were a bit different from the ones in the link but the general idea is there.  Note that the x86 / x64 folders for the acer driver correspond to your operating system version, not the version of android sdk on your system.  I'm on Windows 7 64-bit so I used the one under C:\Program Files (x86)\Acer Inc\ACER ICONIA TAB\Win7\ADB\x64\android_usb.inf

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7:
In my case I just go to Device Manager -> Portable Devices -> Acer ICONIA TAB A100 right click on mouse and Update Driver, after that Compound Device will be installed. And Android USB Devices appear.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the issue on windows 7

1- I open device manager and right click on 'B1-A71' under portable devices and click update driver software.

2- Click on browse my computer for driver software.

**3- Click let me pick from a list of device driver from my computer.**

**4- It will install the usb driver automatically but to make it detect with andoid ecplics you need to install the driver from http://www.acer.co.in/ac/en/IN/content/drivers**

(keep the device connected for all steps)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with `Acer Iconia A510 on Vista`.
Resolved as follows:
Running the driver installer unpacks all the files, then deletes them without installing

- Download driver file from Acer & run
- Check C:\Program Files\Acer Inc\Acer Iconia Tab Driver install at
  each point before clicking 'Next' or 'ok'
- When the driver files appear, copy the whole lot somewhere else
- Continue the process to the end
- The files will have disappeared; copy your copy back to the Acer
  directory
- Plug in the device, and continue the windows driver lookup process
  till it asks if you want to tell it where to look
- Select the directory with the files - windows installs them ok