# Adb can't found Acer Iconia A500

Tags: android, adb

I'm using the android adt bundle.

I have worked without problem with Samsung Galaxy S2 and Samusung Galaxy S4.

But, If I try to connect my Acer Iconia Tab A500, the device can't be found from adb.

I tried to restart the adb:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

But no device is found.

I have installed the Acer Iconia Tab A500 driver, but I obtain the same result.

This is my sdk update state:

```
Android SDK Tools: 22.6.2
Android SDK Platform-Tools: 19.0.1
Android SDK Build-tools: 19.0.3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you got right drivers, then you should see the device, assuming you enabled "USB debugging" on it.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled USB debugging. It is really strange, since I used this tabled one year ago, and all worked good. Now with a new sdk version I have problem

Answer (score 1):

I almost never use specific drivers.
Get Google's driver pack (http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html), and try pointing Windows to it:

1. Remove your old drivers.
2. Install the pack.
3. Plugin your device.
4. Choose "Browse my computer".
5. Point it to {google_sdk_dir}\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\

Here is a detailed tutorial: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php

Comment: Google usbdriver should be only for google device. As said in the documetation:"The Google USB Driver is required for Windows only in order to perform adb debugging with any of the Google Nexus devices."

Comment: "Windows drivers for all other devices are provided by the respective hardware manufacturer, as listed in the OEM USB Drivers document"

Comment: This said, I stand by my statement.
I almost never use the manufacturer drivers. Why should I?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really down to earth but I lost my sanity over the same thing with my Samsung Note II not being recognized.

The OS would be making the "USB device plugged in" sound and all but ADB would not find the device.

Out of desperation I rummaged in my cable box and tried another USB cable. Tadaaaaaa !!

And that my friend is my answer o_O !!

Comment: I have tried four different cable... :( End however with the same cable If I try on the pc of my friend all works good (My friend sdk is not the same version)

Comment: you did check this answer right : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771433/acer-iconia-a500-not-in-adb-devices